# Uncertainity Calculation

Tags: measurement, math, physics, error

>
How can i calculate the absolute uncertainty `dt` in the following case `T=(P/A)^1/4`
 if `P=(5±0.15)` and `A=(0.3±0.009)`

Comment: When uncertainty gets confusing just use min/max analysis.  All other methods are really just shortcuts anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P has a relative uncertainty of ±0.15/5 = ±0.03

A has a relative uncertainty of ±0.009/0.3 = ±0.03

When you add/subtract numbers you add their absolute uncertainties.

When you multiply/divide numbers you add their relative uncertainties.

Therefore, the relative uncertainty in P/A is ±0.03 + ±0.03 = ±0.06. The nominal value of P/A is 5/.3 = 16.67, so its absolute uncertainty is 16.67 × ±0.06 = ±1.0.

You can verify this: The maximum value of P/A occurs when P is maximum and A is minimum: 5.15/0.291 = 17.70. Similarly, the minimum value of P/A occurs when P is minimum and A is maximum: 4.85/0.309 = 15.70.

When you raise a value to a power, you multiply its relative uncertainty by the power. Therefore T has a relative uncertainty of ±0.06 × 1/4 = ±0.015. The nominal value of T is 16.67<sup>1/4</sup> = 2.02, so its absolute uncertainty is 2.02 × ±0.015 = ±0.03.

Again, verify this: The minimum value is 15.70<sup>1/4</sup> = 1.99 and 17.70<sup>1/4</sup> = 2.05.